# What were the C idioms for polymorphism and inheritance before the concepts were made explicit?

Tags: c, history

Suppose I have the usual `class Animal` abstract class and the `class Dog : public Animal` `class Cat : public Animal` that makes it a concrete class you can instantiate an object from. Suppose further that you have a function `foo(Animal a)`, taking either cats or dogs as objects. C++ used to, in the early days, compile to C, and would build a `vTable` maintaining the objects there.

But a student of mine asked me this question: before these concepts were usual talk among programmers, how did they *actually* do it in their day-to-day coding in C? What was (is?) the idiomatic way to program these concepts in C?

I've sifted through the linux kernel, and other OSS projects, but I haven't been able to find a clear pattern: sometimes it's unions (for different structs), sometimes it's function pointers, etc. but I would like a straight answer from knowledgeable people in industry who've done and have a lot of experience with C.

In one sentence: what is idiomatic C for inheritance and polymorphism?

Comment: 1) smart unions 2)function pointers as struct/union members. For an example look at the way how linux handles (block) device drivers.

Comment: I don't think there was an idiomatic way to do it, AFAIK that was one of the selling points of C++. Also this article comes to mind http://www.yosefk.com/blog/oo-c-is-passable.html (on emulating OO in C)

Comment: @wildplasser: Thanks. Are "smart unions" different than "unions"? I'm not familiar with the concept, given that there are "pointers" and then there are "smart pointers".

Comment: Smart unions are unions of similar structs, the first part is the same for all members and (in most cases) it contains a `type` field.

Comment: @wildplasser: Thank you. It would be great if you could write a short answer with an example... for archival purposes :)

Comment: Pascal would use variant records, idiomatic C would use a union of several structs with a common initial sequence, including a type field. As an example: X*Event in /usr/include/X11/Xlib.h

Comment: Please also note that you can write a lot of software without needing _inheritance_ and _subtyping polymorphism_, apparently there is none in Unix V7. You can do many things with a flat hierarchy of types, dispatching on type (e.g: you could have a `foo(int species, union animal a)` function, having `union animal { struct Dog {...}; struct Cat{...}; ...}`, the Berkeley Pascal system in BSD-3 does something similar with AST nodes).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simple programs, such as those written for school assignments, implement polymorphism using a structure that consists of a union and optionally an enum as the type discriminators. Each "method" then contains a switch statement that calls into the function appropriate for the subtype. Obviously this doesn't scale to more systems that require being able to add subclasses without changing the definition of the base class.

Polymorphism itself is easily expressed with function pointers that receive an explicit `self` argument. Open-ended inheritance can be achieved with the "inherited" structure embedding its superclass:

```
struct base {
   // ... members here ...
};

struct inherited {
  struct base base;
  // ... inherited members here ...
};
```

Pointers to `struct inherited` may be safely cast to `struct base *`, a practice explicitly blessed by the C standard. These casts are typically hidden behind macros, which may even perform runtime type checking, where possible.

Implementing this is quite unwieldy, since there are no templates, no automatic invocation of destructors, no exceptions, and no STL. In other words, error handling and destructor invocation must be carefully handled by the programmer, and type variance must be handled either by callbacks at run-time (consider the difference between `std::sort()` and `qsort()`) or by hard to maintain preprocessor tricks.

Despite the difficulties, it is certainly possible to implement a meaningful subset of C++ functionality in C, and even a semblance of simplicity of C in the process. To study real-world examples of this approach being taken to production level, take a look at the implementation of the CPython interpreter, or the glib object system used by GTK+.

Comment: Thank you! It is perhaps this piece of your answer that clarifies quite a bit: "Pointers to struct inherited may be safely cast to struct base, a practice explicitly blessed by the C standard." This helps. I assume that *is* the way they did it, so much so that the standard talks about explicitly.

Comment: @DervinThunk Yes, that's what C++ would call "upcast" and even perform implicitly.

Comment: And how about the opposite: "downcasting", let's say, when you pass `struct base`, in your example, and need to find the "real" object? I guess you could also pass the type of the object in the function, or the type is some enum in the struct? Would that be common practice?

Comment: @DervinThunk Downcasting is performed exactly the same as in C++: by casting a `struct base *` into a `struct inherited *`. To perform the equivalent of an error-checked dynamic cast, one needs a type discriminator. In simpler systems this is a simple enum, and in more complex systems it is a pointer to a detailed structure describing the type, analogous to C++'s vtable pointer.

Comment: @DervinThunk Not only did they do it in the past, they still do it - there is such a thing as modern C code. :) Many Unix programs and services are written in C, and so are typical extensions to popular interpreted languages like Python, Perl or Ruby. Such C code makes heavy use of object-oriented techniques outlined above. For an example, see [this Python 3 PEP](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3123/) which is about migrating a disallowed (but historically accepted) style of structure definitions to the style allowed by the standard.

Answer (score 0):

I saw code that used `#defines` to create abstract names in the source and include files.  for example, the same routine might be re-used to deal with bytes, `short`s, `int`s, `float`s, and `double`s.  The code was messy and hard to understand.

Comment: That would be using x macro to create _generic_ code, not OOP code.

Comment: polymorphism = generics.

Comment: In a C++ context, I believe polymorphism refers to run-time method dispatch enabled by invoking `virtual` methods overridden in a subclass through pointer or reference to a base class. Generic programming in C++ is realized with templates and is not normally referred to as polymorphism.

Comment: @Jim: The OP is clearly talking about _subtyping polymorphism_ (usually known just as _polymorphism_ in OOP circles), while you are talking about _parametric polymorphism_ (usually known as _generics_ in OOP circles, and only known just as _polymorphism_ in functional programming circles)

Comment: @Jim It's a C++ context because the OP is using C++ as reference, both syntactically (`class Dog : public Animal`) and culturally. The question cannot be parsed in a C context, because the term "polymorphism" was never part of the C culture, it's a Smalltalk term that made its way into C++ and became somewhat of a buzzword.

Comment: @user4815162342 is correct. I am not talking about generics, just subtyping.

Comment: You might look at the earlier versions of Rogue/Hack/Hack1.0.3/NetHack.  All of that was done in straight C (even NetHack, I think) and it was pretty complicated in keeping all the items and their capabilities straight.  As I recall the code, tables.  Lots and lots of tables.

Answer (score -1):

Before the advant of object oriented programming, applications were using procedural code where functionality was "encapsulated" in a hierarchy of functions with the ones at the top of the hierarchy working with abstractions and becoming more and more concrete and detailed as we go down the hierarchy. Some API provide ways to create structures that can only be manipulated via handles. Example: In C, file handles hide the details of dealing with files.

As for doing OO in C, I believe it was never a viable option without proper language support with the appropriate constructs. What you would get was not worth the pain involved in faking OO with pointers to functions.

Comment: In my experience most large C programs grew *some* sort of OOP implementation, typically bug-ridden, underperforming and underspecified, as the saying goes. Built-in language support for this style was raison d'être of pre-template C++.